# Finish Only SubActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

How do I use Finish to kill only a subActivity ?

I am launching an Activity C from Activity A

```
public classA {

....

Intent launchC  = new Intent(classA .this, ClassC.class);
     startActivityForResult(launchC  , CodeAtoC);
}


public ClassC extends ClassB{
   ....
   this.finish();
}
```

When I call this.finish() in Class C , I do NOT wish to finish the Super Class Activity ClassB . Is that feasible ? If not , is there a better design I can adopt ?

Thanks.

Comment: when you launch classC, classB isn't being launched as well. Therefore, finishing classC won't leave you with classB.

Comment: Log statements on Activity LifeCyle events , onCreate / onDestroy etc show that ClassB is being launched  as ClassC is launched and enters its lifeCylce .

Comment: Are you doing logging by overriding the onCreate/onDestroy in classB? If you don't override the onCreate/onDestroy definitions in classC, classC will use those definitions from classB.

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivityForResult(launchC  , CodeAtoC);
```

This is only going to launch classC. Extending classB doesn't mean that you create both objects when the classC object is instantiated - it just means that you gain the benefits of class inheritance (access to classB's structure and methods).

A better way of implementing this might be to make ClassC and ClassB into Fragments, and then launch a FragmentActivity from A. You'd use the FragmentActivity to display C, then have it swap in B (via a FragmentTransaction) when you click a button or something, and then return the result to A when you finish.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html